# Deleting rows in numpy array (matrix): Delete previous k rows if value in column j equals k

Tags: python, numpy

I'm working with a numpy matrix, which I'll call A, that consists of n rows and 5 columns.

Suppose all the values in column 2 consist of positive integers or zeros. If A[j,2] equals k, where k is an integer greater than or equal to 2, I would like to drop the previous k rows from matrix A; that is, rows j, j-1, ..., and j-(k-1), from matrix A.

Note if [j,2]=k, the previous k rows will definitely equal 0, so there is no 'overlap'. But these aren't the only elements that equal 0 in this column.

Does anyone have any ideas? I've used numpy.delete and similar functions quite a few times, but just can't generate a solution to this problem.

Example:

```
A = matrix([[9,9,0,9,9],
    [1,2,1,9,9],
    [8,8,0,2,3],
    [7,7,0,7,8],
    [1,2,0,3,4],
    [6,6,3,6,6],
    [1,2,0,1,2]])
```

after the operation, it should become:

```
Anew = matrix([[9,9,0,9,9],
    [1,2,1,9,9],
    [8,8,0,2,3],
    [1,2,0,1,2]])
```

Because the '3' (in the penultimate row of A) meant that the 3 rows(ie the penultimate row + the previous two rows had to be dropped from the matrix.)

Comment: please share an example of your data with the expected output.

Comment: sorry, example now included

Comment: J is user given right?

Comment: j is any row of the matrix--   for j in range(0,length(A)): would be the first line if I was writing a for loop to answer this problem.

Comment: No. A[:,2] only has one element that is greater than or equal to 2, which happens in the second last row, since A[5,2]=3. Because A[5,2]=3, I want to delete 3 rows: The rows with indices 5, 4, and 3 (i.e. the "previous 3 rows")

Comment: Shouldnt this be the output?  matrix([[9,9,0,9,9],
    [1,2,1,9,9],
    [6,6,3,6,6],
    [1,2,0,1,2]])

Comment: No; the 3 rows that get deleted are inclusive of the row that contained the 3 in the column with index 2.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

a= np.matrix([[9,9,0,9,9],
    [1,2,1,9,9],
    [8,8,0,2,3],
    [7,7,0,7,8],
    [1,2,0,3,4],
    [6,6,3,6,6],
    [1,2,0,1,2]])

for i in range(0,7):
    if a[i,2]>=2:
        idx=i
        k=a[i,2]

idxL=[]

for j in range(0,k):
    idxL.insert(j,idx)
    idx=idx-1
a = np.delete(a, (idxL), axis=0)        
print a
```

OUTPUT:

```
[[9 9 0 9 9]

 [1 2 1 9 9]

 [8 8 0 2 3]

 [1 2 0 1 2]]
```

Comment: If you found the answer helpful kindly accept it.Thanks